# Lead-acid uninterruptible power supply safety

Tags: power-supply, lead-acid, lead-free

I use a UPS (Cyber Power, this [one](https://www.cyberpower.com/global/en/product/sku/ut650eg)) that secures my PC from short blackouts.

It is located on the floor in my home office. When recently my kids were playing next to it, I started to ask myself if it's a safe device - it contains a significant amount of lead which could leak somehow and pollute my office unnoticeably.

So the questions:

1. How is the lead battery protected from leaking? If I accidentally flip it from vertical position to a side, will it pose any danger?
2. It seems that most of UPC are based on lead, with a single exception being APC that uses Li-ion batteries ([link](https://www.apc.com/us/en/campaign/lithium-ion-ups.jsp)). Is that a good alternative? I also consider building Li-ion UPS myself.

Comment: Lead (Pb) won't leak; electrolyte will leak if the battery is damaged.

Comment: Lead is solid (at least at any temperature at which it would be still in the UPS in your house). So make sure your kids aren't pulling the UPS apart to get at the lead inside the battery and gnawing on it ...

Comment: *I also consider building Li-ion UPS myself.*  Personally, you and your family are more at risk from this option!

Comment: Well, actually lead toxicity was underestimated for many years (see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HlUm7dXq5s)) and led to average drop of 17 points of IQ in the US (if i remember correctly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The batteries are nominally sealed and will not leak fluid regardless of the position. They have lead (which is a solid metal) and some battery acid, which would be more of an acute concern than the lead if it got into contact with skin (fortunately, it's typically gelled so it can't leak easily, such batteries are marked "non-spillable"). In order to breach the casing the batteries would have to be damaged or defective in some way. Personally, I've never seen it happen accidentally without physical damage. You should, of course, properly recycle them when they (or the UPS) has reached end-of-life. In my area we have no-fee hazardous waste disposal drop-off for household waste which will take paint, lead-acid batteries, fluorescent bulbs and such like.

Lithium batteries have something of a propensity to burst into flames which could emit a bunch of toxic smoke from the smouldering plastic. Personally in such an application where weight is of no concern, I'd stick with the lead-acid.